# no series of functions $f_n(x) = a_n \sin nx +b_n \cos nx$ which converges to the function $1$, $|an| +|bn| ≤ 10$.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, fourier-series

This is a math problem I'm struggling on.

Show that there is no sequence of functions on $[0, 2 \pi]$ of the
type

$$f_n(x) = a_n \sin(nx) +b_n \cos(nx)$$

which converges to the function $1$ almost everywhere on $[0, 2 \pi]$ and where $\lvert a_n \rvert + \lvert b_n \rvert \le 10$.

I haven't seen a problem like this before. I think it may have to do with fourier series, but I haven't learned that yet. Sorry about the poor formatting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if $f_n$ is of the given form, then

$|f_n(x)|\le |a_n|+|b_n|\le 10$. Therefore if $f_n\to 1$ a.e., $(f_n-1)^2 \to 0$ a.e. and is bounded above by the constant $121$. By Lebesgue's bounded convergence theorem:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} (f_n -1)^2(x) dx \to 0.$$

But this is clearly impossible (orthogonality of $(1,\cos(nx),\sin(nx):n\ge 1)$).  To see through direct computation, observe that

$$\int_0^{2\pi} (f_n -1)^2 dx = \int_0^{2\pi} f_n^2 - 2f_n +1 dx .$$ 
Now $\int_0^{2\pi}  f_n dx =0$. Therefore, since $f_n^2\ge 0$, we have

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} (f_n-1)^2 dx \ge \int_0^{2\pi} 1 dx =2\pi,$$

a contradiction.

Comment: Where do you get  "now $\int_0^{2\pi}  f_n dx =0$ "?

Comment: Use this: $\sin(2\alpha)=2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)$.